# 2 Linux scripts nearly identical. Variables getting confused between to different scripts

Tags: linux

I have two scripts.  The only difference between the two scripts is the log file name and the device ip address that it fetches the data from. The problem is that the log file that concats continuously mixes up and starts writing the contents of one device onto the log of the other.  So, 1 particular log file randomly switches from showing the data from one device to the other device..

Here is a sample of what it gets from the curl call.

```
{"method":"uploadsn","mac":"04786364933C","version":"1.35","server":"HT","SN":"267074DE","Data":[7.2]}
```

I'm 99% the issue is with the log variable, as one script runs every 30 minutes and one script runs every 15 minutes, so i can tell by the date stamps that the issue is not from fetching from the wrong device, but the concatenating of the files.  It appears to concat the wrong file to the new file....

Here is the code of both.

```
#!/bin/bash

log="/scripts/cellar.log"

if [ ! -f "$log" ]
then
  touch "$log"
fi

now=`date +%a,%m/%d/%Y@%I:%M%p`

json=$(curl -m 3 --user *****:***** "http://192.168.1.146/monitorjson" --silent --stderr -)
celsius=$(echo $json | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
temp=$(echo "scale=4; $celsius*1.8 + 32" | bc)
line=$(echo $now : $temp)

echo $line
echo $line | cat - $log > temp && mv temp $log | sed -n '1,192p' $log
```

and here is the second

```
#!/bin/bash

log="/scripts/gh.log"

if [ ! -f "$log" ]
then
  touch "$log"
fi

now=`date +%a,%m/%d/%Y@%I:%M%p`

json=$(curl -m 3 --user *****:***** "http://192.168.1.145/monitorjson" --silent --stderr -)
celsius=$(echo $json | cut -d "[" -f2 | cut -d "]" -f1)
temp=$(echo "scale=4; $celsius*1.8 + 32" | bc)
line=$(echo $now : $temp)

#echo $line
echo $line | cat - $log > temp && mv temp $log | sed -n '1,192p' $log
```

Example of bad log file (shows contents of both devices when should only contain 1):

```
Mon,11/28/2022@03:30AM : 44.96
Mon,11/28/2022@03:00AM : 44.96
Mon,11/28/2022@02:30AM : 44.96
Tue,11/29/2022@02:15AM : 60.62
Tue,11/29/2022@02:00AM : 60.98
Tue,11/29/2022@01:45AM : 60.98
```

Comment: Do both the scripts use the same `temp` file?

Comment: see https://linux.die.net/man/1/mktemp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you use "temp" as the filename for a temporary file in both scripts.

I'm not good in understanding `sed`, but as I read it, you print only the first 192 lines of the logfile with your command. You don't need a temporary file for that.

First: logfiles are usually written from oldest to newest entry (top to bottom), so probably you want to view the 192 newest lines? Then you can make use of the `>>` output redirection to append your output to the file. Then use `tail` to get only the bottom of the file. And if necessary, you could reverse that final output.

That last line of your script would then be replaced by:

```bash
sed -i '1i '"$line"'
192,$d' $log
```

Further possible improvements:

- Use a single script that gets URL and log filename as parameters
- Use the usual log file order (newest entries appended at the end)
- Don't truncate log files inside the script, but use logrotate to not exceed a certain filesize

Comment: `tac $log > $log` is wrong, it truncates `$log` before reading from it.

Comment: Thats it.. The scripts are running at the same time and the same temp file name is what is causing the issue.  I did NOT catch that.  Thank you very much.. I am not an expert in linux bash, and i got confused between the $temp variable and the temp file.  Ill do some clean up, and i very much appreciate yours and others input...

Comment: @choroba as I see it, the newest lines are wanted as output, so I first reverse the file so the newest are at bottom, then append the next entry at the end, then tail it, and then reverse again to show the latest line on top. Probably not the most efficient solution ;)

Comment: @cyberbrain: No, have you tried it? `tac $log > $log` doesn't revert the log, it empties it. Before you can read from it, the redirection overwrites it with no contents.

Comment: I did not use the code suggestion, i just resolved the issue with the temp filename.  I modified them to have more unique temp name between the two scripts.  Example :cellar.tmp and GH.tmp .  and as designed, I want to see the newest updates on top so i don't have to scroll down unless i want to go back in history.

Comment: @choroba - got me, didn't try my own solution. So I updated the answer with a strange looking `sed` variant that should do the job by editing the file in place. Please not that the strange newline in the middle of the commandline is required to separate 2 sed commands for inserting the new line and deleting all the rest.

Comment: @cyberbrain: You can try using `$'\n'` instead of the literal newline.